# PagerSlidingTabStrip Error on Rotate

Tags: android, git, pagerslidingtabstrip

I am using PagerSlidingTabStrip which I found on

[Git Hub](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)

the problem is, when selecting tab other than the first tab and rotate the device, the app crashes and throws this error

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

this library is awesome and very useful, but it has some few errors like this. Im using it on a nested fragment. SetRetain is false as I would cause another backstack error if I set it to true.

if you guys met this error and fix it, please help me here... thanks 
i also search the net and look for some info but nothing fix the problem.

- thanks

Comment: please provide more log (the full error message is really helpful). also provide us your manifest, the definition of your PagerSlidingTabStrip instance

Comment: Could not find method android.view.ViewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener, referenced from method com.android.library_htabs.PagerSlidingTabStrip$1.onGlobalLayout

Comment: I would prefer a bit more. But what I'm thinking is that: PagerSlidingTabStrip calls onGlobalLayout inside its notifyDataSetChanged() method, where I supose to cause you app crash. Please show more your logcat: it will tell us at which line of your code you app fails, at which call of your app it fails. One suggestion: in your manifest, set your activity's configChanges to "orientation|screenSize" and see if it works. Also, please give more information. It will help figuring out the cause.

Comment: Ok I am using this PagerSlidingTabStrip inside a dialogfragment, and when I select anything except the first tab, it works just fine, but if not it throws this error, ok wait ill post more logs

Comment: i know its weird, but Im also looking for line number on where the actual error occured, but none. I get the error message via debug break point

Comment: Where did you call your setViewPager(pager) and did you use the method notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66194/discussion-between-nguyn-hoai-nam-and-ralphspoon).